# on NodeMCU, how does WIFI.STARTSMART() work?

Tags: esp8266, sniffer, nodemcu

on http://www.nodemcu.com/docs/wifi-module/#wifi-module-wifi-startsmart, I see code snippet:

```
    wifi.startsmart(6, function() 
       print("Auto config success!")
    end)
```

But what else is needed to make it work?

it seems related to wifi sniffer mode, but I can't find any documentation or example.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example, https://github.com/youngBuger/esp8266-smartconfig

But unfortunately, on latest nodeMCU, which uses v0.9.5 sdk, smart config is broken, as listed here as a TODO item: https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware